# PrimeNG 15 p-table with "column headers" on the left?

Tags: html, html-table, primeng

I am trying to create a primeng p-table, but with headers down the first "column" set to `scope="row"` and then what is normally rows of data as columns.

This is a somewhat common html table type but I can't find any way to do this simply with a p-table.  It seems a long time ago there was a setting for this, but it was removed in release 10.